# Global Event Occur Multiple Times in Blackberry

Tags: events, blackberry, listener, global

I am using global event listener in my application. The event capture perfectly works in my code. The problem is the event seems to be fire multiple time. I have followed this tutorial [link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_Global_Events_and_Global_Event_Listeners.html?nodeid=800527&vernum=0).

Comment: We need more information - what is firing event, what kind of event, maybe peace of your code

Comment: @EugenMartynov public void eventOccurred(long guid, int data0, int data1, Object result,Object object1) listener invoke multiple times in my client app... While ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().postGlobalEvent(0x77c13c897154038L,0,0,res,""); fire...

Comment: I don't have multiple fires in our app. I would suggest you to check that you don't fire it several times. Log both - firing and handling

Answer (score 1):

If your app is listening to global events generated by system, then these events may fire several times according to conditions you do not know. On my experience to get a univocal signal from the system I had to analyze a sequence of global events and the signal was recognized as received only when this sequence of events occured one after another in expected way.

If your app is listening to global events generated by your application, then it is fully under your control. Check your code that fires global events. Use [EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) to log every moment when you fire and when you receive fired event. Then inspect your log to find out what is going on. Seems that your app fires the global event more times than expected.